# Как называются слова, меняющие значение в зависимости от рода: как "машинист" и "машинистка"?

Tags: род, лингвистика

Некоторые слова в зависимости от рода имеют разный смысл, например, "машинист" и "машинистка" — это совершенно разные профессии. Есть ли название у такого языкового феномена?

Comment: Очень может быть, что у таких слов нет названия.

Comment: если явление само по себе очень редкое, то названия оно может и не иметь

Comment: Не совсем об этом, но очень сходные случаи (т.н. феминитивы) обсуждает Кронгауз. Он упоминает пример, что изначально "слово «докторша» обозначало не женщину в этой профессии, а жену доктора." https://chrdk.ru/other/feminitivy У него в Фейсбуке была очень интересная дискуссия на эту тему (месяцев три-пять назад?).

Comment: There is a class of nouns in Spanish which change their meaning with change in gender: _la cometa_ "kite" / _el cometa_ / "comet", _la papa_ "potato" / _el papa_ "pope" etc. They are called "polysemic nouns" (_sustantivos polisémicos_), although "polysemy" is a much wider term. There is another class of nouns which don't change their grammatical gender when denoting an object of another biological sex: _el delfín_ and _la paloma_ mean "dolphin" and "dove" of either sex. This is called "epicene gender". Those terms are the closest things to the answer to your question that I'm aware of.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a new suggestion of my own )

Answer (score 5):

There's no specific term a single word one can use however there are some related terminology. Generally speaking this is a phenomena of `gender-related semantic differences` - when grammatical gender affects the way perceive the word. Technically nothing stops a woman from being called `машинистка` and riding trains or `генеральша` to rule an army however de-facto there exist a shift in meaning because of which when we think of `машинистка` we picture to ourselves woman typing.

When one word has positive connotation and it's counterpart has negative this differentiation is called `gender-related semantic polarization` (in Russian I've seen `семантическая полярность` or `семантическая поляризация`). In Russian one example of such polarization would be the pair `стерва`/`стервец` where "стервец" is way more neutral than "стерва".

In Russian-language articles I've never encountered specific dedicated term however once I've seen `ложная гендерная парность`.

**UPD:** I figured out that on English SE they sometimes come up with their own suggestion if no relevant term has been found. So after some investigation I'm suggesting following term - `квазифеминитив`. So, the word `машинистка` would be a **`квазифеминитив`**, and `машинист`/`машинистка` would be `пара с квазифеминитивом`.